# Keep the class but don't show it in the output of an R function

Tags: r, function, class

After creating a class for an object outputted by a function, is it possible to suppress the extra output (in the below case: `attr(,"class") ; [1] "bob")` not show in the output?

To be clear, I want to preserve the class, I just don't want it to show up in the output.

```
foo <- function(x){

 r <- x + 2
 class(r) <- "bob"
 r
 }
 # Example of use:
 foo(2)

# OUTPUT:   preserve the class but don't show: `attr(,"class") ...`
[1] 4
attr(,"class")
[1] "bob"
```

Comment: You could assign the function output to a variable: `y <- foo(2)`, then just use `as.numeric(y)` to show only the value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `print()` method for the `bob` class:

```
print.bob = function(x, ...) { print(as.numeric(x), ...) }

print(r)
# Output:
# [1] 7
```